# Dynamic Array inside an Dynamic Array

Tags: c, arrays

I have here some sample code that has what I think is needed to solve my problem.

Basicaly I need to store inside an array that has a variable amount of entries a variable amount of reasons for it. Is this `array[5].b[3]` not allowed? Is there any alternative for it?

Thanks in advance

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   char *reasons;
}t_a;

f() {
   int space=10,spaceReasons=5;
   t_a *array;
   array=NULL;

   array=realloc(array,sizeof(t_a)*space);
   array[5].reasons=realloc(array[5].reasons,sizeof(char)*spaceReasons);
   fgets (array[5].reasons[3]),300, stdin);
   free(array);
}
```

Comment: `t_a` has no member named `b`, so this can't work. Be would have to be an array or an initialized pointer, and a capacity of at least 300. Also, `array` is a pointer to `t_a`, but you're trying to access its members as though it was a `struct` of type `t_a`.

Comment: `array.reasons` don't tell me this compiled

Comment: reasons should probably be a `char **`. You access it as `array[0].reasons`, not `array.reasons`. You should probably be allocating the buffer to read into: `array[0].reasons[3] = malloc(300);`. When you free stuff at the end, free all of it, not just the top-level array.

Comment: You cannot call `array.reasons` in __`C`__

Comment: I've eddited the posted code, and tried it on my original code on the compiler. The realloc is being sucessfully done and doesn't output NULL. It crashes at the fgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char* reasons;
} t_a;

int main(void) {
    int space = 10, spaceReasons = 5;
    t_a* array = NULL;

    array = realloc(array, sizeof(t_a) * space);
    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        array[i].reasons = NULL;
        array[i].reasons = realloc(array[i].reasons, sizeof(char) * spaceReasons);

        // fill with fgets
        fgets (array[i].reasons, spaceReasons, stdin);
    }

    // print results
    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i].reasons);
    }

    // first free all reasons
    for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
        free(array[i].reasons);
    }
    // then free array
    free(array);
}
```